# Is there a way to suppress warnings when a package is compiled in elisp?

Tags: byte-compilation, warning, compile

Whenever I compile my package org-ref I get lots of warnings like:
`Warning (comp): openalex.el:622:2: Warning: docstring wider than 80 characters`.

It is a fair warning, but it caused by a hydra with a string more than 80 characters wide that will not be changed. Is there a way to suppress these warnings during a compilation? They make it hard to spot other issues.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See `byte-compile-warnings`:

> List of warnings that the byte-compiler should issue (t for almost all).
>
> Elements of the list may be:

> `docstrings`: docstrings that are too wide (longer than `byte-compile-docstring-max-column` or `fill-column` characters, whichever is bigger) or have other stylistic issues.

Comment: Thanks. I set this as a file-local variable and the warnings went away.